# az storage upload file not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I have been trying to upload a folder to `azure file share` by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-upload-batch), it never works for me, does this really work as mentioned in that link or do we need to do anything extra to make it work. Here is what i did from a shell, just ran the following command as mentioned in that `URL`

```
az storage file upload-batch --connection-string "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=asdadasd;AccountKey=ahdsidyagdasgdhasdghdgasdasjdag4857348574;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" --destination . --source /dfiles/folder
```

And i get the below error

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:af9004d7-301a-0069-26e8-25db2b000000
Time:2020-05-09T09:57:19.5414005Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'gDQ+MYQgNglorkiZ3LkmHHNI56odT4FfxesXUhlK/TY=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT
x-ms-client-request-id:7747952b-91db-11ea-a2c1-000d3af2c73b
x-ms-content-length:90592
x-ms-date:Sat, 09 May 2020 09:57:19 GMT
x-ms-type:file
x-ms-version:2018-11-09
/storage/createdump'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error
```

I am not sure what am i missing here. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying `.` for destination, please try by specifying a `share name`.

```
az storage file upload-batch --connection-string "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=asdadasd;AccountKey=ahdsidyagdasgdhasdghdgasdasjdag4857348574;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" --destination <share-name> --source /dfiles/folder
```

Comment: Awesome! I am glad to hear that.

Comment: is there anything called `az storage directory` for uploading directories?

Comment: If you point your source to a directory, then all the files and folders inside that directory should automatically be uploaded.

Comment: but will it create that folder in the share? example: `source /home/dfiles` `destination sharename/whateverfolderexistsindfilesshouldgetcreated`

Comment: `but will it create that folder in the share?` - I believe no. In my example, I had set the source as `./tasks` folder on my computer and after I ran the command, it did not create that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave a feedback from me also. Do not use --sas-token. For the sas-token we need to use `'<sastoken>'` and it will work properly.

Also use below statement structure and for sure it will work:

```
az storage file upload-batch --account-name <storageName> -d '<shareName>/<example_folder>' --source <source_folder> --connection-string 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storageName>;AccountKey=<accountKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
```

with variables:

```
az storage file upload-batch --account-name $storageName -d $fsName --destination-path <folder> --source <sourceFolder> --connection-string $cs
```